# Получить значение input

Tags: php

На одном сайте есть:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="какое то значение">
```

Как получить значение этого поля?

```
$page='http://lol.ru/';
$titre=preg_match('#<input type="text" name="name" value="[a-zA-Z0-9]">#',$page,$regs);
```

Не работает

Comment: *плохо что ТС даже и предстваления не имеет что он делает*

Comment: Идите в сторону GET или POST запросов. С помощью них получать значения. Вопрос в целом не корректен

Answer (score 1):

Можно распарсить такой регуляркой

```
$text=<<< HEREDOC
<input name=NAME value=test1 /> 
...<input name = "NAME" anytext value="test2" />...
<input value=test3 anytext name=NAME /> 
HEREDOC; 
$re='/<input(?=[^>]*? name *= *(?:"NAME"|NAME)) [^>]*?(?<= )value *= *("[a-z0-9]+"|[a-z0-9]+)[^>]*>/i';
preg_match_all($re, $text, $arr); 
var_dump($arr[1]);
```

Собственно в выводе будет

```
 test1, test2, test3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name=$_GET['name'];
```